# Close Dropzone on button 'Save' click

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

[image]

I'm using Dropzone plugin for uploading images, and I have a little problem with it. After clicked 'Save' button, files POST to the server, but popup still shows in the browser. So, I'm wondering, if this is normal plugin behaviour, and if it's not, could I listen to the click event on 'Save' button, and close a popup after it?

**EDITED**

My html

```
<div class="modal resource-creator-modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Resource</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button form="resource-creator" type="reset" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                <button form="resource-creator" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-loading-text="Proceed...">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initialization of the Dropzone

```
initFileUpload: function() {
    if (this.dropzone) return;

    this.dropzone = new Dropzone(this.$('.dropzone-box').get(0), {
        url: this.options.url.fileUpload,


addRemoveLinks : true,
            maxFiles: 1,
            acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .mp4',
            dictResponseError: "Can't upload file!",
            thumbnailWidth: 138,
            thumbnailHeight: 120,

            previewTemplate: $('#drop-item-preview').html()
        });

        this.dropzone.on('complete', this._onUploadFileComplete.bind(this));
    }
```

Comment: Please add the HTML and Javascript you used.

Comment: Updated my question with html and js

Comment: You didn't add HTML and JS for the save button you used. Or if you've it live, post the URL

Comment: Sorry, about HTML((.I have updated it in my question. About JS, this is only JS I used, for initializing the plugin.

Comment: Submit a codepen or similar that would help us a lot to help you

Comment: This is my code sample
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYWWLw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wasn't able to post complete codes related to the uploader, not able to give you solution based on your uploader. But, if you understand the below code, you'll be able to achieve what you are trying to.

```
this.on("complete", function (file) {
    if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        // Some options to hide the Container or Modal
        $('#file-uploader-container').hide(); // If the uploader is in a Container hide it
        $('#file-uploader-modal').hide(); //If your uploader is in a Bootstrap modal, hide it by applying Display none on the Modal.
        $('#file-uploader-modal').modal('hide'); //By closing modal programmatically. 
        $('#file-uploader-modal #btn-close').trigger('click');  // By triggering Modal's close button (give an ID to call it)
    }
});
```

Depending on your need, apply script on the container or modal. Wish it will solve your issue.

Comment: the best way to close the modal window was to trigger click event on the 'reset' button, wich already doing what I want! So, this is a solution!